# Authenticate to Azure AAD by Java SDK with UsernamePasswordCredential

Tags: azure, sdk

I'm working with azure java SDK and i need to authenticate to azure AAD, since project's business, need to authenticate by 2 ways: client secret and username password. I already worked with client secret. When authenticate by username password, i face this error:

com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalInteractionRequiredException: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxx' named 'yyy'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
I googled for this issue and can't see any correct solution to fix this problem. Is there any way to fix this problem? or i need to grant other permission to this client:

[image]

Below is my sample code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StorageApplication.class, args);

    AzureResourceManager azure = AzureResourceManager
        .authenticate(buildUsernamePasswordCredential(), buildAzureProfile()).withDefaultSubscription();

    showContainers(azure);
}

public static UsernamePasswordCredential buildUsernamePasswordCredential() {
    return new UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder().clientId(YOUR_CLIENT_ID).tenantId(YOUR_TENANT_ID)
            .username(YOUR_USERNAME).password(YOUR_PASSWORD).build();
}

public static AzureProfile buildAzureProfile() {
    return new AzureProfile(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
    // return new AzureProfile(YOUR_TENANT_ID, YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
}

public static void showContainers(AzureResourceManager azure) {
    // TODO
}
```

Below is error when use rest API
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JujfR.png)

Comment: Do you use a personal account that is invited? And check your user consent setting following    [here](https://nishantrana.me/2020/12/01/fixed-aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the-application-with-id/).

Comment: @PamelaPeng no, i use this organization account :(

Comment: It seems all correct if allowing user consent for apps is selected in user consent setting. Could you try to [test in Postman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request)?

Comment: by this docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token, to acquire an access token, only way to authenticate is by client secret, i can't found a way to test this login by rest api with username password

Comment: sorry, i founded a way to acquire an access token by username password and face same error when use SDK. please check this image in above since i can't insert image here

Comment: I found this docs about using username and password to authenticate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc. I will stop using this way to authenticate Azure AD. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's better not to use the ROPC flow. I tried to create a new user in Azure AD to reproduce your error, but it worked well. Some Notes: 1) reset the password when logining with the user account in browser 2) set `User assignment required?` as `No`(navigate to Enterprise Application -> Properties) 3) grant admin consent for the tenant